# Erro de instalação do SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Formatei o note e instalei o windows 10, fui instalar o SQL Server 2012 que sempre usava, mas dessa vez não deu certo.

Veja o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem solução? O erro é conhecido como 1935.

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Por favor, use o campo de pergunta SOMENTE para fazer a pergunta. Você também pode visitar [ask] para melhorar a pergunta e talvez fazer com que quem deu o negativo remova.

Comment: Olá, vou te dar uma dica, tente postar sempre que possível o erro na forma de texto, e não como imagem, pois ajuda na indexação/busca por outros com o mesmo problema. Boa sorte. =)

Comment: bom, eu não estava achando a solução, não tinha mais o que escrever, o erro é exatamente esse da imagem, acho que encher linguiça não ajuda em nada. Mas obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Que bom que achou a solução, você poderia responder sua própria pergunta, adicionando detalhes e passo a passo para a solução, se assim desejar. Você poderá marca-la como resposta em torno de 2 dias.

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou e nem sei o motivo do negativo, mas vou lhe dar duas dicas, primeiro ao invés de imagens copie o texto do erro e cole isso facilita o uso do buscador, segundo coloque respostas no campo de resposta, não somos um fórum somos um Q&A, ou seja o sistema aqui é bem diferente. Seja bem vindo a comunidade.

Comment: pois eu discordo, esse problema me deu muita dor de cabeça, acredito que possa ajudar outras pessoas que passem pelo mesmo. Não vejo o por que não ser um problema relacionado ao sql server, já que o erro foi durante a instalação do mesmo. Acredito que tenha utilidade para programadores que depararem diante desse problema. Mas se quiserem, podem excluir o post, a cada visita me aparece alguma reclamação a respeito, o meu problema foi resolvido, o post está aqui pra ajudar quem passe pelo mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a solução neste vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-a0k1cgU3x0

passos:

execute o cmd como administrador;

digite ou copie e cole no cmd: fsutil resource setautoreset true c:\

apenas isso.